# WS-MakeConnection support in Java

Tags: java, web-services

WS-MakeConnection is specified by [OASIS](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsmc/200702/wsmc-1.1-spec-os.html). My question: how do Java libraries support MakeConnection?

Metro offers some support ([Metro User Guide Chapter 11](https://metro.java.net/guide/ch11.html)).
For server-side, a WS-Policy assertion or an annotation enables support.
For client-side, `MakeConnectionSupportedFeature` can be used to enable support.
Oracle WebLogic support seems to be similar (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-async.htm#WSGET476).
However, this seems to only apply to a sub-set of MakeConnection functionality; specifically, enabling MakeConnection support allows a standard request-response exchange to be converted to the response being received via MakeConnection, as illustrated in section 2.3 of the MakeConnection specification.

I understand that MakeConnection is more general than this. However, it's not clear if the more general functionality is supported by Java libraries. 
A couple of examples:

- Appendix C.1 of the MakeConnection specification shows the example of a notification server, where the client polls for new messages via MakeConnection.
- In the particular situation which I am involved in, the WSDL specifies that the request is sent as "one-way" (input only, no output); the method generated by wsimport is: `void requestX(XRequest request)`. The response is sent some time later (possibly a long time), with two options:

  - Callback from server to client (client has a service for receiving responses, which the server connects to)
  - MakeConnection: client polls server for the response.

In both of these cases, the response is generated outside the context of a particular ongoing SOAP request. Metro (for example) doesn't seem to support these cases – it only support generating the response when the original request is ongoing – within the "requestX()" processing. It doesn't seem possible for the user code to generate a response outside the context of an SOAP request, and to submit that to the underlying JAX-WS server to be made available to MakeConnection requests.

To refine my original question: is this more general MakeConnection functionality supported by any Java libraries?